# Custom shopping cart system

Tags: email, ip, sendmail, shopping-cart, blacklist

Hi We are building a custom shopping cart system using Zend 2.0.  Since we are planning to resell this system and host most of the client's on our own dedicated VPS, I want to know how to manage emails which are generating from the system (Order confirmations, Password resets, register confirmation Etc.)? I don't want these emails end up in spam and most importantly not to get our server IP blacklisted. I see open cart is using SMTP but is this a better method than PHP mailer? What is the best way of doping this?

Answer (score 0):

A service like http://sendgrid.com/ might be worth looking into if you don't mind the SaaS model. You could pass on the costs to your clients.